# CloseApplication while uninstalling - wix

Tags: wix, close-application

I am using Wix 3.6. I have an issue, while uninstalling if any window is open and shown in task bar (this window is a part of my msi, which I am trying to uninstall), it is showing a dialog box asking the user to close the application (“The following application should be closed before continuing the install”).

I tried the following, but no luck.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
       <Custom Action="WixCloseApplications"
                Before="InstallInitialize">Installed</Custom>
       <Custom Action="StartMonitor"
                After="StartServices">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

   <util:CloseApplication Id="CloseMonitor" Target="Monitor.exe"
                           CloseMessage="yes" RebootPrompt="no">
        Installed
    </util:CloseApplication>
```

I want the wix to detect the applications and close them as part of uninstallation process. No need of showing the dialog box prompt. Can anyone please help me to implement it.

It works fine with it is installed from command prompt with /qn switch but without /qn switch I get the dialog (“The following application should be closed before continuing the install”).
Can someone please help me on how to fix this.

Comment: I changed InstallInitialize to InstallValidate and it worked fine <Custom Action="WixCloseApplications"
                Before="InstallValidate ">Installed</Custom>

Answer (score 1):

Add a `C#` custom event and add make it first event on `InstallUISequence` and use following code for kill the process:

```
try
{
      Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplication");
      proc.Kill();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); 
}
```

and if ur application support multiple instances then count the no. of instances first:

```
 int count = 0;
 Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplication");
 foreach (Process pr in process)
 {
   if (pr.MainModule.FileName.Equals(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
       count++;

     }
 }
```

And if you are not at all using and `DllEntry` then follow this [link](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm)

Comment: I was asked not to use C#, so did not try your suggestion.

Comment: see wix has very less inbuilt action or function so you have to use external code. it may be c# or any other language.

Comment: I changed InstallInitialize to InstallValidate and it worked fine <Custom Action="WixCloseApplications" Before="InstallValidate ">Installed</Custom>

Comment: @sanam_bl In that case, give an answer to your own question and accept it. So that in future if u or someone else refer this question may know the solution